# Xamarin.Forms.Maps does not work with Mono Android, v2.2

Tags: dictionary, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use Xamarin.Forms.Maps NuGet package for Xamarin.

But that is not supported to MonoAndroid, V2.2. This only supports MonoAndroid V1.0.

So how should I use Map in my project?

Answer (score 1):

We just need to :

- Right click on xxx.Droid project
- Go to properties
- Go to Application option
- Change Compile using Android version from "Use Latest platform...." to "API Level XX"
- Now try to install Nuget package

That works for me (y)